# replacing one image with another by clicking a "next" button

Tags: image-gallery

Here is my website:
http://mollymasonjohnson.com/project_3/newstyles.html

When you click the "Graphic Design" doll it takes you to the Graphic Design page.  On this page there are thumbnails that when clicked bring up images of my projects.  Some of these projects involve more than one image, so I need to be able to click a "next" button (in this case the little blue arrow on the bottom right)to go from one image of a project to the next.

I tried making an array (to switch from one image within a certain project to the next image within that project) but it didn't work for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off use percents instead of fixed values for the slide. I.e. use 100% instead of -1490px since I'm looking at it on a large screen and can still see the dolls after the slide.

ok the problem is that there is no element with the id you select.  You getelementbyid on gd-project but that is the class and the elements have ids gd-project-1,gd-project-2,gd-project-3, etc.  Furthermore that is the id of the div not the actual image so it has no src property.

try something like (since you have jquery)

```
$(".gd-project img").attr("src",blindsimage[counter].src);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: great! thanks for getting back so quick.  when I replaced   document.getElementById("gd-project").src = blindsimage[counter].src; with $(".gd-project img").attr("src",blindsimage[counter].src); however, it didn't work.  Is that because the ".gd-project img" was not defined?

Comment: hmm maybe it was because there were multiple things which matched that... if you know the id number of the one you want to change you can use that instead.  I.e. to change the image inside of the guy with id gd-project-1 use $("#gd-project-1 img").attr("src",blindsimage[counter].src);  the easier thing might be to give the img itself a unique id...  also alert the blindsimage[counter].src to make sure that is the actual image src you want.

Comment: oh wait I just noticed that the error which it throws is 'update not defined' which means that update isn't being seen from the context of the onclick... try to put a click() handler to call the update from inside of the document.ready function and this should solve it. do  $('#gd-R-arrow').click(function() {update()}); right after you finish defining update.